# How to detect space, and special characters like :, ?,`,~, etc in text of a textfield in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How to detect space, and special characters like :, ?,`,~, etc in text of a textfield in iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
NSCharacterSet* symbols = [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet];
   if([symbols characterIsMember: yourCharacter]) {
        //Check Your condition here
    }
```

If you want to include many characters Use a combined NSCharacterset with NSMutableCharacterSet..

```
    NSMutableCharacterSet *space = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
    [space formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
```

Use the space characterset to check the character

Comment: so if I want to include space and colon in this, how do I write it?

Comment: I tried your code, it checks all symbols but space is not checked.

Comment: Try this  NSMutableCharacterSet *space = [NSMutableCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];

Comment: @iPrabu symbols characterIsMember:(unichar) how to add this unichar i want to do like `instagram` application's # characters and @ character and give them some actions.

Comment: @Hrushikesh check your character like this NSCharacterSet* symbols = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"];

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an instance of `NSScanner` to parse your string. It is a bit more complicated than BuildSucceeded's answer but it's good to know that this exists.

Also when using `NSScanner` you would have to construct the right NSCharacterSet. Look in its documentation to find out how this works.