# Line up three UILabels next to each other and each label can be multiline

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, autolayout

I'am working on a project where I need to line up `3 UILabels` next to each other. Let me explain it with an example.

I have for example the following sentence. `"Tim Moore commented on the little bear story"`
Now my three `UILabels` going to contain:

```
LABEL 1 --> Tim Moore
LABEL 2 --> commented on
LABEL 3 --> the little bear story
```

another example:

```
Dave Smits likes the status "We and only we can me a knew future and only we nobody else can make changes, so don't stop now !"

LABEL 1 --> Dave Smits
LABEL 2 --> likes the status
LABEL 3 --> "We and only we can me a knew future and only we nobody else can make changes, so don't stop now !"
```

Like you can see in the second example the sentence is much longer.

My question is now how can I line these three `UILabels` line up after each other so that I get a nice sentence. The reason why I separate it in three `UILabels` is because I need to set `UITapgestures` on each `UILabel`.

I'm working inside a custom `UITableviewCell` which is using `autolayout`.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: If all 3 labels are multi-line at the same time, isn't it difficult to read? Like below:

Line1 ->>> Tim   --- likes the --- the little ->>> EndOfLine1
Line2 ->>> Moore --- status    --- bear story.->>> EndOfLine2

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom layout of your cell and line up the UILabels with constraints inside the custom cell. Since you are in a custom layout, the constraints should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that piece of code to get your labels lined up. Set numberOfLines:0 to let them be multi-line.

```
-(void)adjustLabels
{
    [self.label1 setText:@"Dave Smits"];
    [self.label2 setText:@"likes the status"];
    [self.label3 setText:@"We and only we can me a knew future and only we nobody else can make changes, so don't stop now !"];

    [self.label1 setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self.label1 sizeToFit];
    CGRect frameFor2 = self.label2.frame;
    frameFor2.origin.x = self.label1.frame.origin.x + 3.f; //add some space between labels
    [self.label2 setFrame:frameFor2];

    [self.label2 setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self.label2 sizeToFit];
    CGRect frameFor3 = self.label3.frame;
    frameFor3.origin.x = self.label2.frame.origin.x + 3.f;
    [self.label3 setFrame:frameFor3];

    [self.label3 setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self.label3 sizeToFit];
}
```

`sizeToFit` method does not work with auto layout, you can have a look at another [answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16009707/1515075) to fix it.

Comment: From the title: "each label can be multiline".