# Get tapped word from UITextView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I know that this problem has been solved in Objective-C, but I haven't seen any solution to it in Swift. I have tried to convert the solution code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-on-ios-7) post, but I'm getting errors:

```
func textTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    var textView: UITextView = recognizer.view as UITextView
    var layoutManager: NSLayoutManager = textView.layoutManager
    var location: CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(textView)
    location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top

    var charIndex: Int
    charIndex = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(location, inTextContainer: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    if charIndex < textView.textStorage.length {
        // do the stuff
        println(charIndex)
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in this line (see error [here](http://pbrd.co/1sglnt5)):

```
 var textView: UITextView = recognizer.view as UITextView
```

... which I have converted from Objective-C based on this line:

```
 UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;
```

Finally, I am also in doubt about how this function should be called. As I understand it, the function should be passed to a Selector in viewDidLoad(), like this:

```
 let aSelector: Selector = "textTapped:"   

 let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
 tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
 view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Because I'm getting the before mentioned error, I'm not sure if it would work. But I'm thinking that I would need to pass the parameter in the textTapped function (recognizer) into the Selector as well. However, I've read that you can only pass the function and not any parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UITextView` that you want to be able to tap.  You are presently adding the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `ViewController`'s `view`.  That is why the cast is getting you into trouble.  You are trying to cast a `UIView` to a `UITextView`.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textTapped))
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
myTextView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Technically `recognizer.view` is an optional type (`UIView!`) and could be `nil`, but it seems unlikely that your `textTapped()` would be called it that wasn't set.  Likewise, the `layoutManager` is of type `NSLayoutManager!`.  To be on the safe side though, the Swift way to do this is:

```
guard let textView = recognizer.view as? UITextView, let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager else {
    return
}
// code using textView and layoutManager goes here
```

In fact, if you had written it this way, you wouldn't have crashed because the conditional cast of the `UIView` to `UITextView` would not have succeeded.

To make this all work then, add attributes to your attributed string that you will extract in your textTapped routine:

```
var beginning = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "To the north you see a ")
var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19.0), "idnum": "1", "desc": "old building"]
var condemned = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "condemned building", attributes: attrs)
beginning.appendAttributedString(condemned)
attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19.0), "idnum": "2", "desc": "lake"]
var lake = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " on a small lake", attributes: attrs)
beginning.appendAttributedString(lake)
myTextView.attributedText = beginning
```

Here's the full `textTapped`:

```
@objc func textTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let textView = recognizer.view as? UITextView, let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager else {
        return
    }
    var location: CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(textView)
    location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top

    /* 
    Here is what the Documentation looks like :

    Returns the index of the character falling under the given point,    
    expressed in the given container's coordinate system.  
    If no character is under the point, the nearest character is returned, 
    where nearest is defined according to the requirements of selection by touch or mouse.  
    This is not simply equivalent to taking the result of the corresponding 
    glyph index method and converting it to a character index, because in some 
    cases a single glyph represents more than one selectable character, for example an fi ligature glyph.
    In that case, there will be an insertion point within the glyph, 
    and this method will return one character or the other, depending on whether the specified 
    point lies to the left or the right of that insertion point.  
    In general, this method will return only character indexes for which there 
    is an insertion point (see next method).  The partial fraction is a fraction of the distance 
    from the insertion point logically before the given character to the next one, 
    which may be either to the right or to the left depending on directionality.
    */
    var charIndex = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(location, inTextContainer: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    guard charIndex < textView.textStorage.length else {
        return
    }

    var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
    if let idval = textView.attributedText?.attribute("idnum", atIndex: charIndex, effectiveRange: &range) as? NSString {
        print("id value: \(idval)")
        print("charIndex: \(charIndex)")
        print("range.location = \(range.location)")
        print("range.length = \(range.length)")
        let tappedPhrase = (textView.attributedText.string as NSString).substringWithRange(range)
        print("tapped phrase: \(tappedPhrase)")
        var mutableText = textView.attributedText.mutableCopy() as NSMutableAttributedString
        mutableText.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], range: range)
        textView.attributedText = mutableText
    }
    if let desc = textView.attributedText?.attribute("desc", atIndex: charIndex, effectiveRange: &range) as? NSString {
        print("desc: \(desc)")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the code in Objective-C (link in my initial post) he's managing NS Range and id value, apparently in order to collect the string, which was tapped. Would you be able to explain how to approach this in Swift as I'm not familiar with the id value notion.  My purpose is to get the string, highlight it when tapped (using NSAttributedString) and load another ViewController based upon the value of the string.

Comment: I have tried to fiddle around with it for a little time now, but I still can't get the grasp of it (formatting code in comments is cumbersome, to link to code is [here](http://pbrd.co/1t30rKc)).

It gives "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", though I think I've written the optional correct.

Comment: How are you creating the attributed string that is in the textView?

Comment: The attributed string is a variable in my Location class ([click here to see it](http://pbrd.co/XIW7D2)). I then make an instance of Location in the ViewController like this: `var someLocation = Location(locationName:"Some place", id: 1)` and add the attributed string to the UITextView in viewDidLoad() like this: `someTextView.attributedText = someLocation.description`

Comment: @wacawama, it works! However, if my TextView is larger than the inputted text and I tap beneath the text (on the empty "whitespace" in the TextView), it will print out the last string. It appears that it is fetching the last charIndex. Is there a way to disregard the tap if it is not directly on top of the text? I have tried setting `textView.textContainer.size = textView.contentSize`, which does not work. The best option seems to be to set the if statement to be `if charIndex < textView.textStorage.length - 1`, but then I can't tap the last character either.

Comment: Weird.  OK, here's the workaround.  Do the `-1` and make your last character a space.  If don't want the space as part of your last string, add an additional string that is just the space.

Comment: Yes it works fine by putting an extra space at the end. Lastly, how would you go about referencing the variable of the tapped string? I would like to be able to edit the attributes of the strings whenever I tap them, so the user gets a bit of feedback. Can I in some way make a similar variable in ViewController.swift and pass the memory address of textView.attributedText to get hold of the original variable from Location (i.e. after tappedPhrase is declared)? I can't figure out, if possible, to work with pointers in Swift.

Comment: See edit above.  I added code to turn the text red when it is selected.  You can either use `setAttributes` to replace all attributes in the range, or `addAttributes` to add additional ones to the range.

Comment: I've been trying to make it so that only one string (the most recent tap) will be highlighted at the same time, but I can't make it happen. [You can see my code here](http://pastebin.com/rPrJHCpH). I've checked that the hashValue of the tapped string matches item.hashValue, so i'm referencing the original variable (most likely!).

Comment: How about just updating the whole string to black before updating the subrange to red, or whatever color you are using.

Comment: It could be the way to go, but, if possible, I would like to keep each individual string attribute/font color, instead of making all strings (apart from the tapped) the same,

Comment: The other thing you could do is store the `range` in a `previousRange` variable in your ViewController and then reset that range back to a non-bold font before updating the new range to bold.

Comment: For some reason it starts giving me an "unexpectedly found nil" error in the `if let idval = textView.attributedText.attribute(...)` part that you provided me with. The error is triggered whenever I tap the text. I have tried restarting, deleting and making a new ViewController (helped a similar issue one time), repasting your code snippets etc. I though that the way the if statement was set up as an optional should prevent this error? Do you have any idea what might cause this behavior? [full source code here](http://pastebin.com/4nkktshw) and [screenshot of error here](http://pbrd.co/YTQi60)

Comment: What happens if you add a `?` like so: `if let idval = textView.attributedText?.attribute(...)`

Comment: I get a "Type Int does not conform to AnyObject Protocol" error

Comment: I changed `idnum` to be an `NSString`. See the edits above. Integers are not objects so they don't belong in a Dictionary of attribute values. My mistake.

Comment: I have tried your edited code, but now it never gets inside the if statement.

Comment: OK.  That tells me your `attributedText` is `nil`.  You need to debug that and find out why.

Comment: If copied everything into a fresh project, and it will now print the `desc` part, but it does not reach or print the stuff inside the `idnum` part, even though both let if statements are the same apart from the first parameter in attribute(...) being desc and idnum, of course. The code is exactly as the one that you've updated. The var that contain the idnum and desc look like this `var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19), "idnum": 1, "desc": "keep going"]`. It seems weird that it can detect desc but not idnum? Changing the name of idnum does not work.

Comment: Ah, `idnum` is an Int, while the let if statement is looking for an NSString. Placing the `idnum` values in " " did the trick.

Comment: I concidered starting a new question about this, but thought to ask here first. When some words/sentences are tapped, the user should get noticed by a fade in/out of the text's alpha value. As I understand it, you can only change the alpha value of the entire TextView. Is it possible to change the text's alpha value over time within a certain range?

Comment: I'd recommend you ask a new question. I'd personally have to research that answer so it would take a while before you got an answer from me.

Comment: If i tap on white space beyond UITextView then it is still showing the character index of last word in UITextView. How to fix it, any help is highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: characterIndexForPoint returns nearest character index incase no character index is found. I have edited the answer and added it's Documentation.

Answer (score 23):

> For Swift 3.0 OR Above
>
> add Tap gesture to UITextView

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnTextView(_:)))
textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

> add tap handler method

```
@objc private final func tapOnTextView(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

  let point = tapGesture.location(in: textView)
  if let detectedWord = getWordAtPosition(point)
  {

  }
}
```

> get word from point

```
private final func getWordAtPosition(_ point: CGPoint) -> String?{
if let textPosition = textView.closestPosition(to: point)
{
  if let range = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(textPosition, with: .word, inDirection: 1)
  {
    return textView.text(in: range)
  }
}
return nil}
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. I needed to get range of word that is tapped in `UITextView`.

Comment: this is works perfectly when text is in English, i'm working with Japanese language (hurigana/furigana) and this doesn't find 'range'.  + 1 FOR YOUR WORK.

Comment: @Vats Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5> solution:

```
// Add this somewhere in the init of the UITextView subclass
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
    target: self,
    action: #selector(textTapped)
)
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

// A method in your UITextView subclass
func textTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = recognizer.location(in: self)

    guard
        let textPosition = closestPosition(to: point),
        let range = tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(
            textPosition,
            with: .word,
            inDirection: .init(rawValue: 1)
        ) else {
        return
    }

    print(text(in: range) ?? "Not found, this should not happen")
}
```