# UITextInput.characterRange(at:) is off by a few pixels

Tags: ios, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, uitextinput, uitextposition

After adding a tap recognizer to my `UITextView` subclass, I'm attempting to get the character that is being tapped:

```
var textRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    textContainerInset = .zero

    textRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textTapped))
    textRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    addGestureRecognizer(textRecognizer)
}

@objc func textTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = recognizer.location(in: self)
    if let cRange = characterRange(at: location) {
        let cPosition = offset(from: beginningOfDocument, to: cRange.start)
        let cChar = text[Range(NSRange(location: cPosition, length: 1), in: text)!]
        print(cChar)
    }
}
```

Problem is that if my attributedText is `"Hello world\nWelcome to Stack Overflow"` and I tap on the left part of a letter, like the left side of letter `f`, then `characterRange(at: location)` returns the previous letter `r` instead of returning `f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective, [`characterRange(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614574-characterrange) is buggy:

- If you give it a point on the left half of character at index `n`, it returns range `(n-1, n)`
- If you give it a point on the right half of character at index `n`, it returns range `(n, n+1)`
- If you give it a point on the left half of character at index `beginningOfDocument`, it returns `nil`
- If you give it a point on the right half of character at index `endOfDocument`, it returns `(endOfDocument, endOfDocument+1)`

The discrepancy of the behaviors at the extremities of the textInput demonstrate that there is a bug somewhere.

It behaves like a sort of "*cursor position at point*" function, which makes it unreliable to determine which character is actually at this point: *is it the character before the cursor or the character after the cursor?*

[`closestPosition(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614523-closestposition) suffers from the exact same issue.

A working alternative is [`layoutManager.characterIndex(for:in:fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1403028-characterindex). [Credit to vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25466154/1033581):

```
@objc func textTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var location = recognizer.location(in: self)
    location.x -= textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= textContainerInset.top
    let cPosition = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
    let cChar = text[Range(NSRange(location: cPosition, length: 1), in: text)!]
    print(cChar)
}
```