# Adding events/actions to an NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I have an NSAttributedString below:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *myString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is my attributed text. Click on here to go to a new controller."];
```

I want to make the word here be an event passing to a new UIViewController. So I want the work "here" to be tapped and passed to a new view.

How do I add a UIButton in there or a tap gesture to it? (Side note, the string can change and the "here" won't always be in the same place).

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-on-ios-7

Comment: True but mine is in a UILabel too.

Comment: You can used that UITextView which looks like label.

Comment: or put UIButton on that specific position and make transition...

Comment: How do you put a UIButton on that specific position? You mean like an overlay or is there a way to add it in as an attribute somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a regular action to an NSAttributedString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908596/add-a-regular-action-to-an-nsattributedstring)