# Add a regular action to an NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I simply want to add an objetive-c action to be called upon a tap on a certain range in my UILabel using NSAttributedString.

But I don't know how to do it. I don't want to open a URL, I just wanna to call a method.

Thanks

Comment: What have you attempted so far? What are you having an issue with?

Comment: If you need a basic starting point, make sure `userInteractionEnabled = YES` and then override the `hitTest:` of your `UILabel` to check point intersection with your various drawn ranges.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use NSLinkAttributeName itself to achieve this. Use an attributed string as shown below and set it as the text of a UITextView.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:termsString];
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:url range:range];
[myTextView setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

And then override the UITextView delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{

// Call your method here.
return YES;
}
```

Dont forget to set the delegate of your textView!

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can just make a simple transparent UITouch like control on top it.
It means that you need to fake it.

Comment: Yes but I think he s looking for a way to do it using the NSAttributedString

Comment: I don't suggest this way also because it's not dynamic.But it really depends on what he wants. You are right also.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you clarified what a "simple transparent UITouch like control" is and how to actually do it.

Comment: Normally, it's a UIButton. Right? Cause he basically wants to add action on it. And you can simply drag and release to connect to the code. I don't suggest that way because it's static.