# NSMutableAttributedString with sound/audio

Tags: ios, swift

For example, I have a line

> This is a test

Upon clicking each word, it produces the corresponding sound. Now going through different approaches to implement it, I found out about `NSMutableAttributedString`. You can add attributes to individual words, like images or fonts etc. My question is, Is there any attribute for adding sounds to group of letters. OR can you plz suggest any better approach? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main task is get notification when user touch a word and to identify the word.

You can add URLs (with special format) to any word and subscribe to a notification when user click it (as delegate to a textView).
For example you can create this URL for "word":

```
soundscheme://word
```

How use URL's with string and subscribes as delegate to UITextView you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908596/add-a-regular-action-to-an-nsattributedstring).
Delegate method can be like this:

```
 -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{

 // Play sound here
 return NO;
 }
```

Also you can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) to get actions when user touch URLs, it supports delegate methods to notify about touches of URLs.

Answer (score 1):

With Attribute string you can get your method called for each word clicked and then you can play the according sound after recognizing the word. 
The attribute string allows you to add custom attributes and then recognize different words categories and apply different actions accordingly

First add recognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
            [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                    action:@selector(textTapped:)];
```

Then in your method

```
- (void)textTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;

    // Location of the tap in text-container coordinates

    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = textView.layoutManager;
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];
    location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left;
    location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top;

    NSLog(@"location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));

    // Find the character that's been tapped on

    NSUInteger characterIndex;
    characterIndex = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:location
                                           inTextContainer:textView.textContainer
                  fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];

    if (characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length) {

        NSRange range;
        NSDictionary *attributes = [textView.textStorage attributesAtIndex:characterIndex effectiveRange:&range];
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRange(range));
      }
}

enter code here
```

if you added a costume attribute

```
[paragraph addAttribute:@"hashtag" value:@(YES) range:wordRange];
```

You can find it with

```
       NSDictionary *attributes = [textView.textStorage attributesAtIndex:characterIndex effectiveRange:&range];


        //Based on the attributes, do something
        if ([attributes objectForKey:@"hashtag"]) {
            NSLog(@"hashtag");
            NSLog(@"clicked: %@",[textView.text substringWithRange:range] );
        }
```