# How can I make each word in a read-only textview touchable so that a pop-up appears when touched?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I make a read-only textview where each word can be touched on to open a popup?

The person will enter text and then submit it. They will then be taken to another page where I want to be able to programmatically make each word clickable in order to show the definition of the word in a pop-up.

At the very least I am looking for the terminology that should google and read up on.

Main question: How can I make words in a read-only textview touchable?

Comment: Were you able to proceed on it ?

Comment: I decided I need to use uiwebview since I need to use <ruby> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to disable editing in textView but keep the cut copy paste or other functions alive, Use below:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    return NO;
}
```

Also do not return NO from textViewShouldBeginEditing to keep the interaction alive.

**Note:** For operation on tapped words, you should use NSAttributedString and add UITapGestureRecognizer to the textView. You can follow the below question:

[Detecting taps on attributed text in a UITextView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-on-ios-7)

Comment: Thanks. How could I make each word respond to touchUpInside?

Comment: You have to use NSAttributedString and UIGesture. Follow this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-on-ios-7