# Trigger an event (tableview reload) whenever a text is in a certain position of a textView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I just started with iOS programming and I could not find anywhere an answer about this.

I have a Textview, containing a large text divided in paragraphs. 
I would like to trigger the reload of a Tableview whenever each paragraph reaches the middle of the TextView.

How could I do it?

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testo: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if databaseDB.open() {

        // Here I definethe string attributes
        var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.lineSpacing = 15
        let font = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0)
        let textFont = [NSFontAttributeName:font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
        let fontSuper = UIFont(name: "Georgia-Italic", size: 13.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0)
        let superFont = [NSFontAttributeName:fontSuper, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:6]

        // and here the variables
        let mainText = NSMutableAttributedString()
        var paragraphId : String = ""

        // I load the text from a table in the database
        let querySQL = "SELECT id, versetext FROM table1"
        let results:FMResultSet? = databaseDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

        while results!.next(){

            paragraphId = results!.stringForColumn("id")

            // I add some other information from another table (here goes also other code, but I have skipped it for simplicity)
            let queryDescrSQL = "SELECT paragraph FROM table2 WHERE id = \(paragraphId)"
             let paragraphResults:FMResultSet? = databaseDB.executeQuery(queryDescrSQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            if paragraphResults?.next() == true {
            // here I add the attributes to the text to be shown
                let numberParagraph = paragraphResults!.stringForColumn("paragraph")

                let paragraphNumber = NSAttributedString(string: numberParagraph, attributes:superFont)
                mainText.appendAttributedString(paragraphNumber)

                let textParagraph = results!.stringForColumn("versetext")+" "
                let paragraphText = NSAttributedString(string: textParagraph, attributes:textFont)
                mainText.appendAttributedString(paragraphText)
            }
        }
        databaseDB.close()
        // and finally everything is loaded on the TextView
        testo.attributedText = mainText
    }

}
// I'm letting out the code for the TableView, as it is probably not relevant for the matter
```

I was thinking of adding some other attribute to `paragraphNumber`, something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-on-ios-7), but I haven't been able to find how to do it.

Thanks in advance,

Silvo

Comment: Please include your current code and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how your paragraphs are divided up (is each in its own `UITextView`, or do they all form one large text view), but the basics of this are that you need to reload a table view when the scroll view reaches a certain scrolled position.

`UITableView` has a method `reloadData`, so call this when your scroll view is at the position.

Scrolling a scroll view just means you are modifying its `contentOffset`, and the scroll view sends its `delegate` a message every time the content offset changes. Make your controller the delegate of the scroll view, and implement the `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` delegate method. In here, check the current content offset, and if it's at the value you're looking for, reload the table view:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    // var scrollView = ...
    // var tableView = ...

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // var scrollThreshold = (calculate some scroll threshold based on your paragraph text)
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollThreshold {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to do this, shouldn't I know in advance the size of each paragraph (which could be quite difficult with a large text)? What if I wanted to reload the tableview each time a new paragraph moves to a certain position? I wasn't thinking of loading each paragraph into its own UITextView, should I calculate the size/position of each paragraph in advance?

Comment: What have you tried? The way you decide to calculate your paragraph size is up to you, and depends on how you're app/views are structured and what you're trying to achieve. String drawing (and hence bounds checking) _can_ be expensive depending how much/frequently you're changing them, but don't optimise prematurely.

Comment: I'll start from the beginning (as a beginner...). I start with an SQLite database, and I want to have a pane in which there is the context Actually, I have first loaded my text on a Tableview (from an SQLite database), with each cell linked to

Comment: Sorry, I keep hitting the return key to move to a new line, and the comment is inserted....

Comment: Can I suggest you append such details to your question - extended chats in comments are discouraged, as they are hard to follow and don't help future readers.

Comment: I'll start from the beginning (as a beginner...). I start with an SQLite database, and I want to have a pane in which there is the content of one table and another pane showing the content from a different table referenced by a specific row in the first table. I initially did everything using two flanking Tableviews, in which each cell in the left pane would trigger the refresh of the right pane. But, I thought that loading the main text from Table1 in a ScrollView would make it look it better (basically, I could present in a book-like manner).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will add the code and everything. How can I append it to the original question now that it is already posted??