# iOS Swift Clickable Text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I need to make text within a UITextView to be clickable.  Basically I want to show more information on the text being clicked on.  In PHP I would surround the text I want clickable in square brackets and then make anything in square brackets a link (i.e. [More Info]).  How can I do something similar in Swift?  I know I can turn on data detectors to detect http links but I don't want http showing.

Comment: I believe this is the same as the question that has been answered here, but in Obj-C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-on-ios-7. If you only want to respond to taps on text by opening links, then you could use a UIWebView instead of UITextView.

Comment: UIWebView was definitely the way to go. Thanks!