# Detect tap on attributed string in a label

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift3, nsattributedstring

I'm creating attributed strings in several positions in a UILabel. 
How can I detect a tap on each one of them, and how can I detect which one has been tapped? Is there a way to do it?

This is how I'm adding my attributed string:

```
    let anotherAttribute = [NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow ]
    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello my name is bla", attributes: anotherAttribute
    attributedString.addAttributes(anotherAttribute, range: NSRange(location: 9, length: 4))
    self.descLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-in-ios

Comment: @Moritz, I believe this is not a duplicate, this question is about UILabel and you pointed UITextView question