# Multiple hyperlink colors in an iOS UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'd like to be able to show a `UITextView` that has multi-colored hyperlinks (ie, some hyperlinks red, some blue, some green, etc.)

No matter what I set `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` to for the given range of the hyperlink it always seems to get overwritten by whatever is specified in `myTextView.linkTextAttributes`.

Is there a way I can disable the `linkTextAttributes` functionality or override its styles on a per-range basis?

Comment: Have you try disabling automatic data detection?

Comment: @Losiowaty Does that prevent automatic link detection (and therefore `shouldInteractWithURL` delegate calls)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably yes - there are solutions to this (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-in-ios ) though. This requires some extra logic to be written. There are also some links in the linked thread about TextKit, which might also be a good place to take a look at.

Comment: UITextView supports HTML, you could use that to format text however you want.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Expected result]

You can find my full tutorial about multiple hyperlink colors here: https://octodev.net/changing-uitextview-hyperlink-color/

Tutorial contains implementation in both languages: Swift and Objective-C.

Would be more than glad to answer all your questions.

Comment: Hi, please avoid posting links to external tutorials. If you have a valid solution you should **cite** the source and a link to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case it's not possible to describe a solution just briefly. I've attached exact and full solution for mentioned problem.