# Replace text with attributed text and add action to it

Tags: swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have array of strings `[apple,mango,banana,kiwi,orange]` 
while the user is typing on textview if the last word is matched to any of the words in the array it should be underlined and have tap gesture added to it .
I am using the

```
         func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool { 
let lastword = textviewtext.lastword()//i have last word i have to replace

        if myarray.contains(lastword) {
    //here code for replacing the text and underline it and add tap gesture 
    }
```

how to do this 
exapmle - user if typed - " **orange** **apple** are good for health  " here the orange and apple should be underlined and should have tap enabled with some actions .like alert with "orange tapped" or "apple tapped"

Answer (score 1):

To underline certain words, you're going to want to use `rangeOfString` to get an NSRange of the word in your text view and create a new attributed string to apply to the text view. Here's an example:

```
let at = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
words.forEach { word in
    if let range = textView.text.range(of: word) {
        at.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
    }
}

textView.attributedText = at
```

To recognize when the word is tapped, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32262426/4431068).

Comment: how to perform this while user entering the text

Comment: @AkashShindhe you would put this code in the method you have already

Comment: its not working -  Cannot convert value of type 'Range<String.Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>') to expected argument type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange')