# How can I perform a segue when clicking on a certain string within a TextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, segue, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to perform a segue when you select a username. I've found answers for linking to a URL, but there is nothing that shows how to segue within the app.

I'm basically trying to implement instagram like behavior.

I think I can use an attributed string, but again that only appears to let you go to a URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting taps on attributed text in a UITextView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-in-ios)

Comment: the say they declare the attributed string no longer works. thanks for the help though

Comment: @NickSteen It still works if you use the correct `UITextViewDelegate`.