# Modify UITextView double tap selection to handle underscores

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

When you double tap on a UITextView, it will by default select the closest word which generally works fine. The problem is that if my textview contains something such as:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

and you double tap on the `table` part of `my_table`, only `table` will be selected, however I want to select the entire `my_table` string.

I can fix this myself by adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and handling double taps, detecting ranges myself and selecting the range myself, however I was wondering if there was anything I could override on UITextView to handle this case (for example macOS has a [doubleClickAtIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1534748-doubleclickatindex?language=objc) method which can be overridden to handle this exact case.

Comment: Maybe `textViewDidChangeSelection:`? Or maybe with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704692/detect-character-tapped-in-uitextview and the `rangeEnclosingPosition:withGranularity:inDirection:`, but not sure if word granularity considered with underscore.

Comment: I think if I customize UITextInputTokenizer -> rangeEnclosingPosition to include underscores for word granularity that should do the trick for me! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Based on your tip I was able to get it working. A first draft is here: https://pastebin.com/2jsUAB7t -- Probably a few bugs, as I haven't tested all to far yet.

Comment: Great if it seems to work. Do not forget to post an answer when it's "fully" done ;)